# Angular 2 AsyncRoute questoin

Tags: typescript, angular

What is the difference between the two RouteDefinitions in the following @RouteConfig?

```
@RouteConfig([

new AsyncRoute( {path:'/customer',
                loader: ()=> System.import('app/components/customer')
                .then(libModule => libModule.CustomerComponent),
                name: 'Customer'
}),
{path:'/order',
                loader: ()=> System.import('app/components/order')
                .then(libModule => libModule.OrderComponent),
                as: 'Order'
}
])
```

...The top one (customer) is an instance of AsyncRoute; is the other also an instance of AsyncRoute?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same since Angular2 creates an AsyncRoute when the `loader` attribute is present in the route definition. See these two lines in the source code:

- AsyncRoute definition- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/router/route_config/route_config_normalizer.ts#L17
- loader attribute in the definition - https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/router/route_config/route_config_normalizer.ts#L41